# Setting up a 3D model on a Marker using Kudan and Swift

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access, kudan

This might be the result of a beginner trying to do something too complex, but I'm trying to use Kudan to model a 3D object on a marker. However, I'm getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Here is my code as it stands:

```
func setupModel() {
    let trackerMan = ARImageTrackerManager.getInstance()
    trackerMan.initialise()
    let trackable = trackerMan.findTrackableByName("image1")
    let importer = ARModelImporter(bundled: "Horse.armodel") //ERROR IS HERE
    let modelNode: ARModelNode = importer.getNode()
    let mTexture = ARTexture(UIImage: UIImage(named: "map.jpg"))
    let tMaterial = ARTextureMaterial(texture: mTexture)

    for i in 0..<modelNode.meshNodes.count {
        let meshNode: ARMeshNode = modelNode.meshNodes[i] as! ARMeshNode
        meshNode.material = tMaterial
    }

    modelNode.rotateByDegrees(90, axisX: 1, y: 0, z: 0)
    modelNode.scaleByUniform(10)

    trackable.world.addChild(modelNode)
}
```

Here is what the console tells me "(lldb)" (as far as I understand it, nothing), and I get "tMaterial ARTextureMaterial! nil" in the screen next to the console.

Can somebody shed some light?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check 「Build Phases」 → 「Copy Bundle Resources」.
Is Horse.armodel there?